# What is the command to truncate a SQL Server log file?

Tags: sql-server, truncate, logging

I need to empty an LDF file before sending to a colleague.  How do I force SQL Server to truncate the log?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

if I remember well... in query analyzer or equivalent:

```
BACKUP LOG  databasename  WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY

DBCC SHRINKFILE (  databasename_Log, 1)
```

Comment: This is definitely better than setting the database recovery model to SIMPLE (as in Blorgbeard's answer) because if your recovery model is FULL, you have it set that way for a reason.

Comment: truncate_only is deprecated in SQL Server 2008 so you have to switch the db to simple recovery http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: For SQL Server 2012 this works, but without `WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY`.

Comment: Adding to what net_prog said, for SQL Server 2012 I substituted the first line for `BACKUP LOG DatabaseNameHere TO DISK='NUL:'`.

Comment: 'TRUNCATE_ONLY' is not a recognized BACKUP option. (SQL Server 2019 RC1)

Answer (score 342):

In management studio:

- Don't do this on a live environment, but to ensure you shrink your dev db as much as you can:

  - Right-click the database, choose `Properties`, then `Options`.
  - Make sure "Recovery model" is set to "Simple", not "Full"
  - Click OK
- Right-click the database again, choose `Tasks` -> `Shrink` -> `Files`
- Change file type to "Log"
- Click OK.

Alternatively, the SQL to do it:

```
 ALTER DATABASE mydatabase SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
 DBCC SHRINKFILE (mydatabase_Log, 1)
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx

Comment: Your answer has just saved my day! I didn't know of the "right-click - Tasks -> Shrink" option. Thank you!

Comment: What DO you do in a live environment?  Backup the logs first?

Comment: I'm no DBA, but yes, I believe that backing up the log will truncate it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179478.aspx

Comment: @JohnBubriski If you're using a recovery model other than simple, the logs are the basis for recovering data or rolling back transactions. So, in production, you'll need to backup these logs first before you can shrink the log files. Otherwise, there'd be no actual recovery possibility. Unfortunately, if you're in a recovery situation, you'll have to re-load all the transaction log backups in order to fully recover the DB. Fun times, to be sure! :)

Comment: in SQL Server 2012 I had to `use mydatabase` before executing `dbcc shrinkfile`

Comment: Note: The log file is usually called `DatabaseName_log` but it can differ. You can find the name of the file for the current database with `SELECT name
FROM sys.master_files WHERE database_id = db_id() AND type = 1`

Comment: Also the `1` in the shrink command refers to the intended size of the log after shrinking. The default is the original log file size, which is why some answers in this question have a value and some don't. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I have seen the script runs faster than the 'Tasks -> Shrink -> Files' option. DB size is mostly 200+ GB. If I run using the GUI it takes more than 15 mins every time. But script takes max 10 secs to do this. Any idea why GUI takes time?

Answer (score 84):

For SQL Server 2008, the command is:

```
ALTER DATABASE ExampleDB SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
DBCC SHRINKFILE('ExampleDB_log', 0, TRUNCATEONLY)
ALTER DATABASE ExampleDB SET RECOVERY FULL
```

This reduced my 14GB log file down to 1MB.

Comment: As the question is ambiguous as to which version and the accepted answer isn't applicable to SQL Server 2008 this answer is still valid regardless of age.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me reduce a big Log file that didn't react with DBCC SHRINKFILE

Comment: Don't forget to change the recovery model back to FULL when you are done!

Comment: You should backup before doing this (or any of the other truncation options). If you do a full backup and check the 'Copy only backup' in SSMS then you don't need the log anymore. (This is just a point in time backup).

Answer (score 40):

For SQL 2008 you can backup log to `nul` device:

```
BACKUP LOG [databaseName]
TO DISK = 'nul:' WITH STATS = 10
```

And then use `DBCC SHRINKFILE` to truncate the log file.

Comment: This is the only one that ended up working in my situation... I got an error when trying to use backup with TRUNCATE_ONLY

Comment: Note: this can take quite a while, even on SSD (it has to read the log to be able to discard it). For a 30GB log file on an moderately powered Azure VM it's taken 10 minutes to do 40%. Make sure to switch to the 'Messages' take in SSMS to see the percentage processed.

Answer (score 3):

backup log logname with truncate_only followed by a dbcc shrinkfile command

Answer (score 1):

Since the answer for me was buried in the comments. For SQL Server 2012 and beyond, you can use the following:

```
BACKUP LOG Database TO DISK='NUL:'
DBCC SHRINKFILE (Database_Log, 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option altogether is to detach the database via Management Studio. Then simply delete the log file, or rename it and delete later.

Back in Management Studio attach the database again. In the attach window remove the log file from list of files.

The DB attaches and creates a new empty log file. After you check everything is all right, you can delete the renamed log file.

You probably ought not use this for production databases.

Comment: Never do this! There can be data in the log not yet committed to the data file. You would lose such data.

Comment: If, in your answer, you warn not to try it in production, it's not worth posting at all.

Comment: I disagree with the downvoters -- it is an option.  Administrators just need to understand their scenario.  For example -- there will be no 'uncommitted' data if there are no open transactions.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. My drive was filled up and I couldn't backup or shrink and nothing else seemed to be working. Thank you!

Comment: I agree; it's not a best practice but it's valuable a tool to have if you have no other options such as Brian's scenario.

Comment: Also if your database that's ballooning is a test database anyway, the reason the log file is ballooning is because you're throwing huge piles of data at it for stress-test purposes, and you really don't care about being able to restore from a backup. :p