# How to reduce log size of database in SQL Server 2008 r2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a database with mydb.mdf file size in 4GB and **mydb.ldf** is **400GB**, how to reduce this log .ldf file?

Comment: If `FULL` - `BACKUP LOG`, If `SIMPLE` - `DBCC SHRINKFILE`

Comment: Already tried ... but no effect on log size

Comment: Please answer on the first question... We don't have a crystal ball

Comment: [How to shrink the SQL Server log](http://rusanu.com/2012/07/27/how-to-shrink-the-sql-server-log/)

Comment: I think your problem solved by following links
Try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829542/how-do-i-decrease-the-size-of-my-sql-server-log-file