# Why the .bak file size is much larger than the restored database(SQL)

Tags: sql-server-2008

Why the .bak file size is much larger than the restored database.

here .ldf size is 298 GB and .mdf size is 50 GB.
   And i am running job for database backup daily.
   After backup the .bak file size is 348 GB.
   I dont need .bak file with log data.
   Can we ignore log data while running backup job only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think it's possible to backup only mdf file without it's complementing log. Individual files can be backed up but again the complete set would be needed to restore it back.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/18/sql-server-file-backups/

The following links seem to address the problem you are facing to a good extent.

[What is the command to truncate a SQL Server log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402/what-is-the-command-to-truncate-a-sql-server-log-file)

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/backup-log-with-truncate-only-in-sql-server-2008/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the backup routine is appending the new backup to the same file?

There is an option in the Backup dialog in Sql Management Studio to Append or Overwrite all existing backup sets. If you have Append if will add the backup to the same .bak file and the .bak file will be larger for every backup.